# Debezium: Produce messages only upon changes to columns in column.include.list

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I am running Debezium with `column.include.list` configured to a subset of columns on each of the observed tables of the source MySQL database. Changes to records on the source tables are being successfully published to Kafka, with each message's values `before` & `after` only containing that subset of columns.

However, Debezium still publishes messages when changes occur on columns of the observed tables that are *not* in `column.include.list`. Those events are unnecessary to my downstream consumers, so I'd like to prevent them from being produced.

**I only want changes to columns found in `column.include.list` to produce messages to Kafka. What is the preferred way to do this?**

Using [SMT Filtering](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html) seems like one way to do it—a filter that compares the `before` & `after` values and filters out any messages in which there is no difference. Is there a simpler way? Maybe a config for this behavior I missed in my search?

Comment: Which debezium version are you using?

Comment: Interesting! I'm running `2.0.1`.

Comment: Related https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-2979

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment, Forgot I had manually done that filtering :D

Comment: With SMTs you can possibly use transforms.filter.condition=value.after.getMap().equals(value.before.getMap()). Can you give it a try?

Comment: Have you tried using the ExtractNewState SMT? Then inspect the fields you get?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want messages produced to have the full Debezium structure, but I only ever want to produce messages when any `before` & `after` values have changed.

Comment: @RonakJain issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-2979 describes exactly what I'm looking for, nice find.

Comment: @jbarr Correct, I'm looking to contribute in the same. Did SMT worked for you?

Comment: Not yet, although I assume it will work fine. My original question was really to inquire if the behavior is offered as an out-of-the-box feature somehow.

Comment: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-5283 describes a very similar feature and has an open pull request that looks like it will be merged. Might be a nice reference for someone looking to contribute the feature described by issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-2979 ;)

Comment: @jbarr Cool! I'll take a look at that in that case, for now, should I add  issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-2979 as my official answer to this question ?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the answer to "What is the preferred way to do this?" is currently by using a SMT.

Comment: @jbarr I will add, thanks! I'll try with SMT as well once I am in a position to, have you tried cherry-picking the PR?

Comment: Nope, have at it! XD

Comment: @jbarr In case you still need this, I've done the changes and this should be available in next release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

This should be doable now that my PR is merged (upon the next release).

https://github.com/debezium/debezium/pull/4378

(From our discussion in the comments)

There's an open issue describing exactly what you expect, but not yet been picked up for development.

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-2979

Thus it seems currently you need to rely on SMTs to filter events/messages not related to monitored columns.

Comment: hmm why your change is gone in most recent version?https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/2.6/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlChangeRecordEmitter.java

Comment: @zonyang Some refactoring was done in a follow-up PR, the option is available - see doc https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.5/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-skip-messages-without-change